# Integrating Redis into Apollo Server

Tags: redis, graphql, apollo

Planning to integrate Redis into Apollo as described here: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/performance/cache-backends/#single-instance

Can anyone advise how would I know or how to determine if the Redis integration is successful?